# RAM Free decreases over time due to increasing RAM Cache + Buffer

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory

When visualizing some memory related metrics on server level, I get a chart which looks like this:

[image: Chart]

The area below the blue line is `RAM Used`. The area below the red line and above the blue line is `RAM Cache + Buffer`. The area below the black line and above the red line is `RAM Free`. The area below the orange line and above the black line is `SWAP Used`.

As you can see in the chart: `RAM Used` is slightly decreasing over time (or at least it is not increasing). But RAM Free is decreasing as well due to an increase of `RAM Cache + Buffer`.

We try to estimate if this server will run out of memory in the future and therefore created a trend line for `RAM Free` which is obviously decreasing and therefore the trend analysis suggests that there is no `RAM Free` anymore in the near future and memory problems will occur.

My questions are now:

- Is this a valid approach or should we rather focus on a combined metric (e.g. `RAM Free` + `Ram Cache + Buffer`) or only `RAM Used`?
- Is a strongly decreasing `RAM Free` and an increasing `RAM Cache + Buffer` a dangerous sign regarding the available memory or is this nothing to worry about?
- If this is no valid approach at all, what can one derive from such a visualization or from such  metrics?

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Free RAM is wasted RAM; the fact that the amount of free RAM is low on your system is a good sign, not a bad one.

What’s important is the amount of RAM used by applications, and stalls related to excessive swap use. In your case, the amount of RAM used is low compared to the amount installed, and there isn’t anything to be concerned about.

On this type of graph, the only things to watch out for are excessive swap use and excessive RAM use, and even then the only self-sufficient indicator is excessive RAM use. Excessive swap use is only a concern if there’s excessive swap *activity*, *i.e.* the system is spending too much time swapping pages out and back in, and you can’t see that from this graph.

Comment: Two additional questions: You mentioned that a huge amount of Free RAM is wasted RAM Would this also mean that if there is a lot of Free RAM it could make sense to even reduce RAM? And it which point would you speak of excessive RAM usage? E.g. if there are a lot of fluctuations over time with some peaks above some limit? Or also if one observes a relatively constant RAM usage of 90% e.g. with not a lot of fluctuations?

Comment: I said that free RAM is wasted RAM; even if there aren’t huge amounts of free RAM, it’s still wasted. That’s why the kernel uses as much as possible for caches: anything in the cache can save I/O later. Excessive RAM use needs to be determined by watching usage patterns: consistent 90% use with little I/O could be OK, and consistent 60% use with heavy I/O or a periodic memory-consuming task might no tbe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! :-)

Comment: May used + free + buffer/cache give an incomplete picture in those (uncommon?) cases in which a relevant part of cache is not reclaimable (e.g. tmpfs)? (Assuming the definition of this "used" is the same as `free`'s).

Comment: @fra-san Perhaps, but if you are using tmpfs to store gigabytes of data for some time, you really should add enough swap to back it. If you don't, you're essentially forcing the kernel to reclaim recently used file cache pages instead of long inactive tmpfs data, causing unnecessary thrashing and wasting RAM.

Comment: @StephenKitt To add to this explanation why free = wasted. I/O not only takes more time but also - what matters for an average joe -  *wears down the hardware*. I remember there were always issues with first <insert your r/w storage hw> due to missing/disabled caching, SSD had something in the beginning too. That means the place which should securely store data persistently is being destroyed far more for no reason while a cheap piece of hw is just sitting there. Now what is cheaper to replace, RAM over a span of 5-10 years (if ever)  or a fresh and modern <favorite storage> and *its data*? :)